# How do I deploy ASP.NET boilerplate WebApi class library as a stand-alone web service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-boilerplate

I am using ASP.NET boilerplate for the first time. I have been able to apply the **ApplicationName.Core**, **ApplicationName.Application** and **ApplicationName.ORM** (NHibernate) libraries with success.

However, I need to make my application services available as a web service. My understanding is that once I deploy the library named: **ApplicationName.WebApi** as a web application to IIS, I automatically have a web service which exposes my application services through /api/services/.

When I did this, I kept getting error 404.0 as shown below when I try to make requests to the API over my browser:

[image: Error 404.0 for WebApi]

I need some advice on where exactly I am getting things wrong. My thought is that I might have to add some additional configuration to the web.config of the application.

The current configuration is like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>  
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Default" connectionString="***" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http.WebHost" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Collections.Immutable" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.0.34.0" newVersion="1.0.34.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Castle.Core" publicKeyToken="407dd0808d44fbdc" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.3.0.0" newVersion="3.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="AutoMapper" publicKeyToken="be96cd2c38ef1005" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.4.0" newVersion="4.0.4.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.webServer> <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
        <handlers>
            <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
            <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
        </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to deploy **ApplicationName.Web**. ApplicationName.WebApi is a class library.